# Include PHP file using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a Javascript file that submits a form and loads an alert etc. Now I want to add functionality to call or get a `.php` file, I tried using `$.get("mail.php");` but it doesn't seem to work.

Javascript Code:

```php
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('action') + $(this).serialize());
    alert("Thank You! \nTop Up for: <?php echo "$username" ?> Purchased Successfully");
    $.get("mail.php");  //this is the added part to get mail.php//
    location.reload();
```

PHP - `mail.php`:

```php
<?php

$to = "stephan@mail.co.za";

$headers = "From: website mail \r\n";

$email_body = "has just toped up his account.\n".

$email_subject = "User Topup Alert";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: can you please post you php file also

Comment: What do you expect `$.get("mail.php")` to do? Do you want it to display something on the screen, or just send an email? (or something else?)

Comment: just send mail , the mail.php works 100% when loading it in webpage

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form

Comment: forms action is a url that the javascript loads but does not view it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can try `load()`:

```
$("#mailDiv").load('mail.php');
```

According to me `$.get` and `$.post` are to send the data. You cannot include files using this.

Comment: whats the issue .. ? it will load the content of mail.php in html element whose id is mailDiv.. I hope the extension of file where you have added the js code has php extension ..

Comment: @StephanBotes its ok mate .. it happens sometimes .. good to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('selector').load()
```

OR

```
$.ajax();
```

`$.ajax();` is most preferable.

Comment: how to use $.ajax() in php ?